# Ruby: how to check if a file is still open?

Tags: ruby, io

Ruby's documentation reports that the use of File.open with a block automatically closes the file, otherwise suggests to explicitly close the file with method close.
Supposedly, if someone forgets to close the file in the latter case, the file stays open. How to check if the file is still open and eventually close it?

If I decided to open the file with the IO class and create a new I/O stream using IO.new(fd):

```
fd = IO.sysopen("file.txt", "a")
myios = IO.new(fd)
myios.puts "new line"
```

would the stream be automatically closed once the code is executed? How can I check it?
The use of ObjectSpace.each_object(IO) does not help to understand if myios stream is closed by the garbage collector or by Ruby once the code is executed.

Comment: autoclose? → true or false
Returns true if the underlying file descriptor of ios will be closed automatically at its finalization, otherwise false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasonable (=all) OSs close fds automatically when a program ends, no matter what the code does.

As for ruby code trying to be nice during execution, Ruby has finalizers that autoclose when a variable that used to reference a filedescriptor (or an encapsulated filedescriptor) gets garbage-collected.

On a UNIX system, you can check open files with lsof.

The code below demonstrates the concepts:

**rb.rb**:

```
def func()
    fd = IO.sysopen("file.txt", "a")
    myios = IO.new(fd)
    myios.puts "new line"
end
func
sleep 3 #most likely open here unless the GC managed to run
GC.start #should be closed after this point
sleep 3
```

Now if you invoke it with:

```
$ ruby rb.rb  & pid=$!; while kill -0 $pid; do if lsof -p $pid | grep -q file.txt; then echo open; else echo closed; fi; sleep 0.3; done
```

you'll probably get one "closed" (before the ruby code catches up), 3 seconds of open and then 3 seconds of closed.

If you don't want to rely on finalizers (which are will run at indeterministic times, because they rely on the garbage collecter), then the block syntax for opening files is really nice in ruby -- the end of the block will deterministically close the file at the very point where the block ends.

Answer (score 9):

You can call [IO#closed?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-i-closed-3F) on the file object:

```
f = File.open('stuff.txt', 'w')
p f.closed?  # => false
f.close
p f.closed?  # => true
```

Keep in mind that unless you hang on to your file variable, Ruby's garbage collector will eventually find the file and close it.  However, I think the best practice is to close files as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely manage this yourself.

You can use the `closed?` method from `IO` class to test this state. You can read about it [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-closed-3F).

There are methods that automatically close.  Many will automatically close if you invoked with a block.

As a less elegant approach you can rescue an exception if the file is not able to be worked on.